# Angular2 - Fire event on Leaflet-Event

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, leaflet

I am trying to impement Leaflet with Angular 2 TS for my Ionic 2 app. I want to emit my **pinClicked**-event when a Leaflet-pin was clicked. How to do this? In Angular1 $scope.$apply was the solution...

```
private refreshMarkers() {
    L.marker([40.731253, -73.996139])
      .addTo(this.map)
      .on('click', function() { alert('JA'); } );
  }

  private pinWasClicked() {
    this.pinClicked.emit('');
  }
```

Comment: can u share ur source code to have look?

Comment: I think you don't need further code.. There are two functions. With on() I subscribe to the 'click' event and want to execute the pinWasClicked() function.

Comment: Have you tried `on('click', () => this.pinWasclicked())`?

Comment: Yes: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at e.fireEvent (leaflet.js:6)
    at e._onMouseClick (leaflet.js:7)
    at HTMLImageElement.s [as _leaflet_click18] (leaflet.js:8)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:256)
    at HTMLImageElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:423)

Comment: Please check this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/tHoaxmtzsJ6W3e1qYHpq?p=preview What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tryed .on('click', pinWasClicked );

Comment: Thank you @yurzui. Do you want to write the answer? Would be great if you can tell me, what this syntax means? () =>

Comment: @yurzui , your code does a great job of triggering a function in the parent component, but it doesn't seem to carry any data with it.  You pass a n empty string with the emit method, but I can't see how to access that data in the app component.  Any ideas?  I've tried gal007's suggestion, but that doesn't fire the function in parent at all.

Comment: @carpiediem Check this  https://plnkr.co/edit/tHoaxmtzsJ6W3e1qYHpq?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private refreshMarkers() {
let marker=L.marker([40.731253, -73.996139]);
  marker.addTo(this.map);
  marker.on('click', 
             (e)=>
             {this.pinWasCliscked(e)} );
}
private pinWasClicked(e) {
console.log(e);
this.pinClicked.emit('');
}
```